# Are swap partitions supported on Elastic Beanstalk with Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We're running a docker container on AWS Beanstalk and on the Docker platform; 'Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2'
Have followed these guides to setup a swap-partition that is visible when running the command 'swapon'.

Guides:

http://steinn.org/post/elasticbeanstalk-swap/

https://gist.github.com/steinnes/1f8a1b44fed4b136005f

When the docker instance is running and using all available memory, the process is immediately killed. No swap-space is being utilized.

Have also tried experimenting with various settings in the docker-compose.yml, but nothing seems to be working.

```
mem_limit: 16g (or omitting this setting)
mem_reservation: 8g (or omitting this setting)
memswap_limit: 48g or -1 
mem_swappiness: 0
privileged: true (tried this only to rule out that it had something to do with access rights)
```

I'm dead in the water on this one. Have any of you practical experience with creating swap partitions on Beanstalk Docker and actually verifying that the swap-space can be utilized by the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

When deploying the new build to EB, it fails to list docker containers with out of memory error. After this happened, re-deplying to the EB shown as success, but actually none of the changes were applied. (I added `.platform/hooks/prebuild/setup_swap.sh` similar to the URL in the question)

It seemed like the process didn't run because of out-of-memory, so that adding swap was not possible.

I ended up manually adding swap to the instance with `eb ssh`, after that everything worked just fine.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of experimentation, I've found that it's possible to configure swap when using AWS's own 'Dockerrun.aws.json' instead of docker-compose.yml.
AWS has the documentation for it here. The docs are targeted towards ECS but works with Beanstalk as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-swap.html

The documentation adds the 'linuxParameters'-object to the Dockerrun.aws.json-file as shown below.

**'maxSwap'**: The total amount of swap memory (in MiB) a container can use.

**'swappiness'**:  A swappiness value of 0 causes swapping to not occur unless required. A swappiness value of 100 causes pages to be swapped aggressively

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "linuxParameters": {
                "maxSwap": 48000,
                "swappiness": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32375461)